# Unable to install pythonmonkey on ubuntu 18 ERROR: Could not build wheels for pythonmonkey, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, pip

I try to install pythonmonkey in windows 10 using pip and anaconda it's working fine,
but when I try to install pythonmonkey in ubuntu 18 linux using miniconda in myserver it getting error

I have fresh env in miniconda then I run command `pip install pythonmonkey` but I got this error

```
(py3917) admin@server:~$ pip install pythonmonkey
Collecting pythonmonkey
  Using cached pythonmonkey-0.2.1.tar.gz (112 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Collecting pminit (from pythonmonkey)
  Using cached pminit-0.2.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_27_x86_64.whl
Building wheels for collected packages: pythonmonkey
  Building wheel for pythonmonkey (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for pythonmonkey (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/tmp/pip-install-ph7wqk6v/pythonmonkey_34995c194ff54c12b4582084f0010eb0/build.py", line 61, in <module>
          build()
        File "/tmp/pip-install-ph7wqk6v/pythonmonkey_34995c194ff54c12b4582084f0010eb0/build.py", line 55, in build
          execute("git submodule update --init --recursive", cwd=TOP_DIR)
        File "/tmp/pip-install-ph7wqk6v/pythonmonkey_34995c194ff54c12b4582084f0010eb0/build.py", line 27, in execute
          raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(return_code, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'git submodule update --init --recursive' returned non-zero exit status 128.
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/admin/miniconda3/envs/py3917/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "/home/admin/miniconda3/envs/py3917/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
        File "/home/admin/miniconda3/envs/py3917/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
          return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7_kl5896/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/api.py", line 58, in build_wheel
          return WheelBuilder.make_in(
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7_kl5896/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 88, in make_in
          wb.build(target_dir=directory)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7_kl5896/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 123, in build
          self._build(zip_file)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7_kl5896/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 172, in _build
          self._run_build_script(self._package.build_script)
        File "/tmp/pip-build-env-7_kl5896/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/poetry/core/masonry/builders/wheel.py", line 266, in _run_build_script
          subprocess.check_call([self.executable.as_posix(), build_script])
        File "/home/admin/miniconda3/envs/py3917/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 373, in check_call
          raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
      subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/admin/miniconda3/envs/py3917/bin/python', 'build.py']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pythonmonkey
Failed to build pythonmonkey
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pythonmonkey, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

this is my version I'm using of miniconda, python, pip, node npm

```
Linux Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

(py3917) admin@server:~$ conda --version
conda 23.9.0
(py3917) admin@server:~$ python --version
Python 3.9.17
(py3917) admin@server:~$ pip --version
pip 23.3.1 from /home/admin/miniconda3/envs/py3917/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
(py3917) admin@server:~$ node --version
v18.16.0
(py3917) admin@server:~$ npm --version
9.5.1
```

can someone help me? Thanks

I have create new fresh environtment in miniconda to deploy my application in server ubuntu, then I install the dependency and I got error in dependency `pythonmonkey`, how can make it work for install?